# ASMX support multipart/form-data?

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx, multipartform-data

i have a WFC webservice that receives a stream data by a http request that works fine.
Now, im tring to make same webservice in .Asmx, but the webservice always reposnse me: 415 Unsupported Media Type

Now, its possible that a .asmx accept a multipart-form/data?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, I've successfully done that.

Not sure where your problem lies... could it be the client? (edit: what client are you using?)

How you inspected the network traffic already ?

Comment: Please provide and link/example to do so.